# Which version spring are supported by ActiveMQ 5.11.1

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

Which all versions of spring are supported by ActiveMQ 5.11.1?

I was connecting to ActiveMQ 5.10.0 broker using spring config's. I was using following jar's:

```
spring-2.5.0/spring.jar
spring-3.0.5/org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

With ActiveMQ 5.11.1, I was wondering whether to upgrade spring jar's or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Spring version that ActiveMQ 5.11.1 is shipped out of the box with. Which is `spring-core-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar` eg Spring 3.2.11 release.